# Why are some questions not getting so many views?

Tags: discussion, questions, popularity

I often have problems programming and I always post questions. I see some of my questions get a lot of views while the others did not.

I know that more people will look at questions with popular tags such as java, c# and android. But my popular questions have roughly the same tags as the ones that are not popular.

Less popular questions:

[How to make TextToSpeech speak faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706444/how-to-make-texttospeech-speak-faster)

[Why is the dimen resource inconsistent and how to get the correct value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183961/why-is-the-dimen-resource-inconsistent-and-how-to-get-the-correct-value)

[How to interpret this log message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181901/how-to-interpret-this-log-message)

[SuagrORM : Why is listAll method throwing NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194300/suagrorm-why-is-listall-method-throwing-nullpointerexception)

More popular questions:

[What is wrong with my if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933043/what-is-wrong-with-my-if-statement) (And somehow this is tagged with `pascal` and it gets > 100 views!)

[How to "check" a cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165290/how-to-check-a-cast)

[Why my TextView under an ImageView is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816586/why-my-textview-under-an-imageview-is-not-showing)

I really don't understand why this happens. What are the factors affecting views? Are my questions too hard? Or are they not interesting?

Comment: Your *what is wrong with my if statement* link **is** Pascal, so I'm not sure what problem you're having with the tag. The language used in the code is Pascal. FreePascal and Delphi are both based on object-oriented Pascal, and both are currently maintained and used.

Comment: Pascal (in the form of FreePascal and Delphi) is as current as most other languages. Delphi in general supports generics, closures, inheritance, polymorphism, operator overloading, and is cross-platform for Windows 32/64, OS X, iOS, and Android. The fact you think it's *shit* is irrelevant, because your opinion doesn't matter. Language snobbery due to lack of knowledge just highlights your lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The title of the question is super duper important.  It is what everybody sees first, you have only one shot to make a good impression and to get somebody to actually view the question.  Extra important these days, you are competing with eleven thousand other SO users that ask for help every day.  What stands out in the questions with the low views are the "scary" words.  Roughly:

- "TextToSpeech": blah, library without knobs, probably a machine problem
- "dimen": sounds like a Japanese noodle problem
- "interpret": he's trying to hack code he didn't write
- "SuagrORM": ugh, he doesn't care enough to spell sugar correctly.

Writing a good title is a bit of a science.  Only simple advice is to ensure capitalization and spelling are flawless.  Broad advice is to make it sound interesting, think like a book author.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and cursory glance at your questions show that they're asked during the weekend - specifically around Saturday.  Stack Overflow has, historically, had lower page views over Friday and Saturday.

It could also easily be the case that those questions are the sort that a casual on-looker may not be able to formulate an answer to in the short time that they have.  While that is unfortunate, that is also another factor to consider.